# Why is accessing openai api through secret manager killing the kernel on my jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-api

Here is the code that is causing the kernel to crash

```
import openai_secret_manager
import openai

secrets = openai_secret_manager.get_secret("openai")
print(secrets)
```

I am not sure why this code is killing the kernel. Any help would be appreciated.

I tried asking Chatgpt but I did not get an answer.

I tried running the code on google collab. This is the error I got - RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.